# How to reset value of jquery jRange slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I am using jQuery jRange slider to show time of video on my page. when I am changing my video url at that new time is not appending to slider.

It shows min and max value of previous video.

Here is link of api : http://nitinhayaran.github.io/jRange/demo/

Please help me out.

```
$("#video_url").change(function() {
  player.pause();
  var currtime = player.currentTime();
  var dirtime = player.duration();
  addSlider(currtime, dirtime);
  jQuery(".annodds").change(function() {
    $(".annodds").val(this.value);
  });
});

function addSlider(currtime, dirtime) {
  jQuery('.annodds').jRange({
    from: Math.round(currtime),
    to: dirtime,
    step: 1,
    //            scale: [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100],
    format: '%s',
    width: 300,
    scale: false,
    showLabels: true,
    theme: "theme-blue",
    isRange: true,
    onstatechange: function() {
      $(".annodds").trigger('change');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: can you please create a sample on http://jsfiddlet.net ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to change the slider values :

```
$('.annodds').jRange('setValue', 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/nitinhayaran/jRange/issues/5). You can simply use the `setValue` to set the desired value for your range selector

```
$('.annodds').jRange('setValue', 0);
```